# How can i get Transaction Id using Authorize.Net SIM method

Tags: authorize.net

How can i get(return) Transaction Id using Authorize.Net through SIM method ?

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

1. [Relay Response](http://www.authorize.net/support/SIM_guide.pdf)
2. [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/)

Comment: Hi @john-conde , I've got a question i was hoping you could maybe help me with. If you get a chance can you check out my post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281553/get-order-transaction-id-from-authorize-net-authorize-aim